# Select next cell JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would like to make a jTable in which when user select an uneditable cell then it should change  focus to the next editable cell automatically. Important: the user could select a cell by keyboard (tab or arrow) and by mouse clicking. Is it possible?? How to to it?

Comment: I don't understand how using a SelectionModel causes the focus to go to a cell that is editable. Why don't you post your code so others can learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link details [Programmatically Making Selections in a JTable Component](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/Sel.html); you'd have to have mouselisteners/etc chained to work off this.

Answer (score 1):

[Table Tabbing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/04/table-tabbing/) shows how you can do it with the keyboard.

I've never tried it but you should be able to use a MouseListener to invoke the same Action when you click on a cell.

Just did a quick test for the MouseListener and it seems to work fine:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...);
final EditableCellFocusAction action = 
    new EditableCellFocusAction(table, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB"));

MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter()
{
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        JTable table = (JTable)e.getSource();
        int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        int column = table.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());

        if (! table.isCellEditable(row, column))
        {
                ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent(
                    table,
                    ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,
                    "");
                action.actionPerformed(event);
        }
    }
};
table.addMouseListener(ml);
```